# Can't select `schema` whose name includes number

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using postgresql 11 and `node-postgres` library in nodejs application.

I use this below method to select different schema:

```
await client.query(`SET search_path TO test38`);
await client.query(...)
```

I always got `error: relation "Customers" does not exist` error if I use a schema with number in its name. It works fine if I remove the number. It works fine via command line.
Is it a bug in this library? Is there any other method for me to change the `search_path` to select different schema?

I have tried quote on the schema name but it doesn't work and give me the same error:

```
await client.query(`SET search_path TO "test38"`);

await client.query(`SET search_path TO 'test38'`);
```

Comment: Then it must be that there is no such table in the schema. Please [edit] your question and add evidence to the contrary.

Comment: What does `select count(*) from test38."Customers";`  give you?